# Изменить текст и стиль кнопки «Добавить в корзину» с помощью AJAX на странице WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Я использую код, который изменяет текст и стиль кнопки «Добавить в корзину» для товара, добавленного в корзину.

```
/* for single product */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'single_product_button_text' );
 
function single_product_button_text( $text ) {
 
    if( WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( get_the_ID() ) ) ) {
        $text = 'Product in Сart';
    }
 
    return $text;
 
}
 
/* for archive/category pages */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'products_button_text', 20, 2 );
 
function products_button_text( $text, $product ) {
 
    if( 
       $product->is_type( 'simple' )
       && $product->is_purchasable()
       && $product->is_in_stock()
       && WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product->get_id() ) )
    ) {
 
        $text = 'Product in Сart';
 
    }
 
    return $text;
 
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'action_wp_footer' );
function action_wp_footer() {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            var selector = '.add_to_cart_text:contains("Product in Сart")';
            
            // Selector contains specific text
            if ( $( selector ).length > 0 ) {
                $( selector ).addClass( 'product-is-added' );
            } else {
                $( selector ).removeClass( 'product-is-added' );            
            }
            
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

После добавления товара в корзину мне приходится каждый раз обновлять страницу, чтобы получить новый текст и стиль кнопок.

Далее я использовал код для изменения текста и стиля кнопки с помощью AJAX. Текст меняется, но все стили ломаются.

```
add_action('wp_footer','custom_jquery_add_to_cart_script');
function custom_jquery_add_to_cart_script(){
    if ( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ): // Only for archives pages
        $new_text = __( 'Product in Сart', 'woocommerce' );
        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                // Ready state
                (function($){
                    $('a.add_to_cart_button').click( function(){
                        $this = $(this);
                        $( document.body ).on( 'added_to_cart', function(){
                            $($this).text('<?php echo $new_text; ?>');
                            console.log('EVENT: added_to_cart');
                        });
                    });

                })(jQuery); 
            </script>
        <?php
    endif;
}
```

Как я могу исправить этот код в своем вопросе? Может есть более корректный вариант кода?

Буду рад вашей помощи!

Answer (score 0):

Возможно кому-нибудь пригодится данный ответ. Моя тема имеет много кастомного кода, включая шаблоны списка товаров, поэтому вам нужно поменять стили под свои нужды. Либо можете этот код усовершенствовать.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_button_text_js_script' );
function ajax_button_text_js_script() {
    $text = __('Product in Cart', 'woocommerce');
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            var text = '<?php echo $text; ?>',      $this;

            $(document.body).on('click', '.ajax_add_to_cart', function(event){
                $this = $(this); 
            });

            $(document.body).on('added_to_cart', function(event,b,data){
                var buttonText = '<span class="add_to_cart_text product-is-added">'+text+'</span><i class="cart-icon"></i>';

                $this.html(buttonText).attr('data-tip',text);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Код нужно добавить в файл functions.php вашей дочерней темы. Код протестирован и работает.